# Error Code: DeclaredProgramIdMismatch

Tags: anchor, pda, error

I am trying to run some tests in my Solana Anchor project but I get an error saying that the declared program id does not match the actual program id.

```
Error: AnchorError occurred. Error Code: DeclaredProgramIdMismatch. Error Number: 4100. Error Message: The declared program id does not match the actual program id.
```

Here's the steps I take:

1. Build my program (`anchor build`)
2. Deploy using local testnet (`solana-test-validator -r`)
3. Copy paste the program id that comes out after deployment
4. Stop the local testnet
5. Run the tests (`anchor test`)

My rust program declared id is:

```
declare_id!("hqgrvUepLLhFbXCb8woduWM62ps5rqap3TmPHbpuK11");
```

But if i try to paste the client's program id I get this:

```
ProgramId: PublicKey {
  _bn: <BN: da075cb2ff5ec6817613de530b692a8735477769da47430cbd8154335c4a8327>
}
```

My question is, how do I further debug this? I've looked for the error inside node_modules to see what is compared that throws such error but I could not find much.

Thank you in advance,
Happy coding.

EDIT_1:

Test client:

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { Program } from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { BoyncAnchorProgram } from "../target/types/boync_anchor_program";

import { PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { expect } from "chai";

describe("boync-anchor-program", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);
 
  const program = anchor.workspace.BoyncAnchorProgram as Program<BoyncAnchorProgram>;

  it("Creating user Bob", async () => {
    // Add your test here.
    const [bobUserPDA, _] = await PublicKey
      .findProgramAddress(
        [
          anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode('user'),
          provider.wallet.publicKey.toBuffer(),
        ],
        program.programId
      );

    const tx = await program.methods
      .initialize('Bob')
      .accounts({
        user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
        userData: bobUserPDA,
      })
      .rpc();

     ^^^ ERROR at this transaction invocation.

    console.log("[Success] Your transaction signature", tx);

    const bobData = await program.account.boyncUserData.fetch(bobUserPDA);
    expect(bobData.name).to.be.eql('Bob');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FIXED:

Searched for the name of my program in the project directory and found out that it was a mismatch in the Anchor.toml file.

```
[features]
seeds = false
[programs.localnet]
boync_anchor_program = "EkvnvRY2prU1sJpVLHBk5qsNMXBryaZeMVacRSE1pcZM"
```

I changed the pubkey to match the one declared in the program code and everything worked.

A clean rebuild did not worked. I wonder how the Anchor.toml file got stuck with a different programId. A bug probably?

Answer (score 7):

I saw you found the solution, but the issue is more related to the Anchor workflow, which is not correctly explained in the Anchor book as far as I know.

When you are compiling a Solana program built with Anchor for the first time, it goes like this:

1. Run `anchor build`

   - This generates the `target/` folder.
   - Inside this folder, you'll find `deploy/` and in there a keypair file. The keypair file is a generated keypair for the program you are deploying.
2. Run `solana-keygen pubkey target/deploy/{keypair_file}.json`

   - This will give you the public key of that keypair
3. Copy that public key and update it both on `Anchor.toml` and in `lib.rs`, where the macro `declare_id!()` resides.
4. Run `anchor build` again, in order to re-compile the code with the new program id.
5. Lastly, if you want to deploy it in localnet, I recommend using `anchor localnet` instead of the vanilla `solana-test-validator -r` since it deploys the program located on `target/` for you using that keypair.

You only need to do the first 3 steps the first time you build the program, or in case you delete the `target/` folder or the keypair inside it changes.

Hope this clarify things :)